# Spatial query not showing results

Tags: mysql, sql, spatial

I'm using spatial query to find some places in a radius for the given lat. and long.

```
select *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(radians(1.0)) * COS(radians(`lat`)) * COS(radians(`lng`) - radians(1.0)) + sin(radians(1.0)) * sin( radians(`lat`)))) AS distance
FROM table_name
HAVING distance <= 5
ORDER BY distance
```

This is not returning any values. Is there any problem with the query?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you don't have a `GROUP BY` clause.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(radians(1.0)) * COS(radians(`lat`)) * COS(radians(`lng`) - radians(1.0)) + sin(radians(1.0)) * sin( radians(`lat`)))) AS distance
      FROM table_name
     ) t
WHERE distance <= 5
ORDER BY distance
```

If you are using MySQL, the documentation explicitly warns against this use of `HAVING` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).  I don't think the query will parse in any other query engine, so I'm guessing you are using MySQL (the SQL standard would require that `DISTINCT` be in the `GROUP BY` clause if it is in the `HAVING` clause).

Comment: i guess 't' should come inside the brackets.